# Where can I download the LuaEclipse plugin from

Tags: eclipse, lua

Where can I download the LuaEclipse plugin from? The link on the [luaeclipse.luaforge.net](http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net) page is broken.

BTW, I can't use the eclipse update site http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/update-site/site.xml due to firewall issues. So I need to download archive of the LuaEclipse plugin, which I than will extract locally and can point eclipse to.

Answer (score 1):

The Lua Development Tools look like a new version of the eclipse plugin:
See : http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/ldt/

Answer (score 0):

This link is working:
[LuaEclipsePlugin](https://github.com/luaforge/lua-eclipse-ide)

There you can download it as a zip file.

Comment: You are pointing to the [lua-eclipse-ide](http://luaforge.net/projects/lua-eclipse-ide/) plugin, not the [LuaEclipse](http://luaforge.net/projects/luaeclipse/) plugin. From a technical point I don't know which one is better to use (any suggestions?), but according to LuaForge only LuaEclipse seems to have a public license.

Answer (score 0):

The below link is the latest URL for lua plugin for Eclipse (to be used from inside Eclipse):

http://download.eclipse.org/ldt/releases/milestones/